# Can a CartoDB-Torque map be used for polygon instead of a point data?

Tags: carto, point-in-polygon, torque

Can you use Torque for country data - polygons instead of points? Make animated maps with polygon data instead of point data? I would like the color of countries to change over time as a particular variable gets smaller and larger.

Comment: No, you can't do that, torque deals entirely with points. You would either need to use the sql api and set the css on the layer each time or use something like d3js, which will do dynamic chloropleths directly on the client.

Answer (score 2):

What @John Barça says in the comment above is true.

No, Torque does not work with polygons. The [Torque wizard](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#torque) is only available for points. Alternatively, there are other options that you could use to show different polygons with respect to time:

The JavaScript API, CartoDB.js, enables you to add interactivity to your maps. 
In combination with our SQL API, you can build a time-slider and show different polygons depending on how they evolve with respect to time. You can find an example of it here: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/time_slider.html